# Remove element after returning a value from it

Tags: jquery, return

I'm trying to create an element, set a value to it, and, return that value and then remove the element. Obviously the last part doesn't work, because `return` ends the function. How would I go about this?

```
function myFunc(a) {
    var d = $("<div>");
    d.css("color",a).appendTo("body");
    return d.css("color");
    // Everything below this line won't execute
    d.remove();
    console.log("executed");
}
```

For those who are curious, I'm using jQuery's `css` to return any given color value as rgb(a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not store the value you want to return in a variable? Then return it when everything else is done

```
function myFunc(a) {
    var d = $("<div>");
    d.css("color",a).appendTo("body");
    var color = d.css("color");
    d.remove();
    return color;
}
```

Comment: D'oh! I've been coding all day. I should take a break. Silly mistakes are starting to slip into my work. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

How about setting it to a variable first?

```
function myFunc(a) {
    var returnedColor,
        d = $("<div>");

    d.css("color",a).appendTo("body");
    returnedColor = d.css("color");

    d.remove();
    console.log("executed");

    return returnedColor;
}
```